# Respond to HTTP Post in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, http-post

I'd like to respond to an HTTP POST in an ASP.Net page.

I've found loads of example of sending an WebRequest, and I can successfully pick that up and read it in my Page_Load.

However, I'd like to then put some data back in the Response, but I can't find any examples of how to do this.

The actual requirement is for an external site to POST to a page and receive back a GUID for their records.

Any help very gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically ASP.NET page will put its rendered markup (html generated by controls present on it) in response. Going by your requirement, I would suggest you to use generic HTTP handler (.ashx file) that will give you complete control over your response.

See this article for quickstart with ashx: http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_(ASHX_Files).html

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should be using an HttpHandler and not a `Page`.
You create an HttpHandler by implementing the [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) interface. When implementing the `IHttpHandler` interface, you have full control over the response in the `ProcessRequest` method.